# Relative Hitchin-Kobayashi correspondence and relative Hermitian Yang-Mills connections

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, kahler-manifolds

Let $\mathcal E\to X$ be a stable vector bundle over a polarized projective manifold $(X,\omega)$.We know, that in this case $\mathcal E$ admits Hermitian-Einstein metric, i.e., a metric $h$, such that (may be up to some constants)

$$
{\rm tr}_\omega F(\mathcal E, h)=\lambda \rm Id,
$$
where

- $F(\mathcal E, h)\in \Lambda^{1,1}(T^*M)\otimes \rm End(\mathcal E)$ is the curvature of Chern connection on $(\mathcal E, h)$
- ${\rm tr}_\omega\colon \Lambda^{1,1}(T^*M)\otimes \rm End(\mathcal E)\to \rm End(\mathcal E)$ is a contraction with $\omega$
- $\lambda=\int_X c_1(\mathcal E)\wedge\omega^{n-1}/\int_X \omega^n$.

Let $\pi : X\to\Delta$ be a degeneration of  Hermitian-Einstein metrics $(X_s,\mathcal E_s) $ , then

$$
{\rm tr}_{\omega_s} F(\mathcal E_s, h_s)=\lambda(s) \rm Id,
$$
where here $\lambda (s) $ is the fiberwise constant. Then under which condition the relative vector bundle $\mathcal E_{X/\Delta}$ admits relative Hermitian-Einstein metric? When can we get uniqueness on it? since in general $h_s=h_s'+f (s)$ and $f (s) $ is a test function .

$$\frac{\partial^2 h_t(s')}{\partial s'\partial t}=-2h_t(s')(\Lambda F_{h_t(s')}-\lambda (s')Id)$$

In fact we are facing with Hyperbolic PDE instead parabolic PDE :)

In this case $s'=\frac {1}{s}$ where $s'\to \infty$ since $s\to 0$
. In fact we have two times $t, s'$ for this deformation. In Donaldson flow we can get the canonical metric by deforming the metric by one time $t $ while in this case we have two times.

In fact the relative vector bundle is not a vector bundle near central fiber. My conjecture is that when central fiber is Kahler manifold, then we can get a stability on relative vector bundle. In fact in general the central fiber is Moishezon when general fibers are projective. Moreover  the [singular Hermitian metric](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238825/chern-classes-and-singular-hermitian-metrics-on-vector-bundles) is not well defined on the central fiber $(X_0, \mathcal E_0)$. So we need to impose some condition such that $h_0$ to be well defined. [See this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268627/uniqueness-of-singular-hermitian-einstein-metric-along-yau-donaldson-flow)

In general, I think after possible [semi stable reduction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1048), on the disc $\Delta $, the central fiber admits Hermitian-Yang Mills connection.

Hassan Jolany